# Display div on hover flickers constantly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When a user hovers over the **?** glyphicon, I want to display a information card which follows the mouse around.

I achieved this with the below code, but then hovering over the icon, the div flickers constantly like a strobe light when using **Chrome**.

In IE it works fine, and in Firefox the div doesn't appear at all

Why?

**HTML**

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
<div id="machinesInfo" class="infoCard">
    some cool text
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
    $('.infoCard').css({
        left:  e.pageX,
        top:   e.pageY
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.infoCard {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

.glyphicon-info-sign:hover + .infoCard {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: because you move the mouse with the infocard... so on hover you make it block, no more hover, its none, hover again, block again, no hover, and so on ---> flickering !! ... make it a bit far from the mouse, add a small offset to left/top

Comment: @TemaniAfif My hero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjusted my JS to

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
    $('.infoCard').css({
        left:  e.pageX + 20,
        top:   e.pageY + 20
    });
});
```

and it now works great